# PHP Memory exceeded while writing to array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I need to update a value in an array inside a loop. Normally this works fine, but something about this loop is causing the memory to max out.

```
while ($watering_window['total_run_time'] > $water_window_total)
{
    foreach ($master_schedule as &$_ms)
    {
      $current_soak_time = $_ms['between_starts'] - $_ms['total_run_time'];
      if ($current_soak_time > 0)
      {
          $new_soak_time = ceil($current_soak_time * 0.9);
          $_ms['between_starts'] = $_ms['total_run_time'] + $new_soak_time;
          $watering_window['total_run_time'] -= $current_soak_time - $new_soak_time;
      }
    }
}
```

Something about writing to `$_ms['between_starts']` (an existing key) is causing the memory problem. If I change it to write  a NEW key (like `$_ms['between_starts_new']`, no memory problem. I also tried writing a constant value to it (instead of something mathy) and it still timed out.

Comment: doesn't look like the braces for the if ($current_soak_time > 0) are closed

Comment: Thank you, jcorry. That was a transcription error. In my actual code there's a conditional that shows the user a message if the current soak time is not > 0.

Comment: Is it an infinite loop? Does $watering_window['total_run_time'] > $water_window_total ever evaluate to false? Using a debugger makes troubleshooting stuff like this so much easier...

Comment: I don't think it's infinite because when I take out the write statement, or I change the name of the key, it completes the loop without a memory problem. I believe the problem is specific to writing to the existing key—is it possible that writing to that value is creating an infinite loop because of the way I'm using it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the reference to your `&$_ms` value? It could be what's causing `$_ms['between_starts']` to balloon in size (continuous increment), and in turn, cause `$current_soak_time` to *also* balloon, thus not allowing `$watering_window['total_run_time'] > $water_window_total` to ever return false. Or do you require `$_ms` to be referenced for other reasons?

Comment: @Marcus, I'm not sure. I'm using the & (this is what you're referring to as 'reference') because I need to write to this array while I'm making these computations. Your theory seems plausible—and possibly in line with what I'm already trying, writing a temporary version of the array and then copying it to the original when the loop is complete.

Comment: Well, as you continuously *write* to `$_ms['between_starts']` with your addition, it grows in size; each iteration. It is then used in your `$current_soak_time = $_ms['between_starts'] - $_ms['total_run_time'];` calculation, but with each iteration, `$_ms['between_starts']` is getting larger and larger and larger which is making `$current_soak_time` larger and larger and larger. You then use `$current_soak_time` to manipulate the `$watering_window['total_run_time']` value, but it's forever growing in size so `$watering_window['total_run_time']` will *always* be `> $water_window_total`

Comment: But as you stated in another comment: "*there's a ridiculous amount of domain knowledge in this code*". Couldn't be more true. I haven't a clue what your application is designed to do/what its purpose is. Do you need to be updating `$_ms` by way of reference in your loop? I don't know. I don't know where `$_ms` is required elsewhere in your application; therefore, I can't simply tell you to remove the reference. And yes: `&` = a reference.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're thinking. `$_ms['between_starts']` is supposed to be getting smaller each time, as `$new_soak_time` is iteratively reduced by ~10% of `$current_soak_time` with each loop.

Comment: `$watering_window['total_run_time']` is supposed to be getting smaller, but it can't because `$_ms['between_starts']` keeps getting bigger and bigger. And in turn, because of that, as does `$current_soak_time`. That's how I see it, anyway. You'll have to rewrite your logic and determine whether the reference is actually necessary in this case, because it's directly affecting the outcome of your loop(s).

Comment: The short answer is, yes, I need the reference. But I am going to have to rethink the logic as you noted. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to increase the `memory_limit`.
Add the following at the top of your php script:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
...
```

Adjust the value according to your needs.

Comment: My memory limit is currently set to 134,217,728 bytes. There must be a way to solve the problem without changing the memory limit.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably need to change your code but I don't have the slightest idea of what you're trying to do...

Comment: Yeah, there's a ridiculous amount of domain knowledge in this code. I hoped that whatever I'm doing wrong would be obvious enough that understanding what the code does wouldn't matter... Essentially I'm iteratively reducing an amount of time until the conditions of the while loop are met. Each time I reduce it, I need to update the array in case that's the last time it gets updated. Maybe there's a better way to do this last part?

Answer (score 2):

Try unsetting the key that is causing the problem before you set it.

```
foreach ($master_schedule as &$_ms)
{
  $current_soak_time = $_ms['between_starts'] - $_ms['total_run_time'];
  if ($current_soak_time > 0)
  {
      $new_soak_time = ceil($current_soak_time * 0.9);
      unset($master_schedule['between_starts']);
      $_ms['between_starts'] = $_ms['total_run_time'] + $new_soak_time;
      $watering_window['total_run_time'] -= $current_soak_time - $new_soak_time;
  }

}
```

Comment: Great suggestion. It doesn't seem to have resolved the memory issue though. I tried it with your latest edit, too.

Comment: @JessycaFrederick, have you tried dumping the value of `$_ms` while it's looping to see if it's growing?  Have you also tried doing it without using a reference?

Comment: I don't think I have tried either method because I'm not sure what you mean. (I'm not an experienced programmer.)

Comment: I've tried unsetting the value on its own (as you've shown) without the subsequent write statement and it creates an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh, ok.  So instead of using something like `echo` do `var_dump($_ms)` before the error occurs in the code.  It should print the contents of the `array` so you can see what is happening during the execution of the code.  If you don't know what I'm talking about with the reference, don't worry about it for now.  Just find out if the `$_ms` array is growing, or if any other arrays are growing.  Because that is what is most likely causing the issue.